# Using deprec with passenger and nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, deployment

Has anyone come up with a recipe for installing Phusion Passenger fronted by nginx instead of Apache?
Or at least some automated way of installing those two, that works alongside a cap/deprec deploy?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the [passenger](http://www.modrails.com/) site has a rails cast for Passenger + Nginx.